# Deploy Plotly Dash on Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, plotly-dash

I was wondering if it's possible to deploy a Plotly Dash on Sharepoint?
Instead of using github to store data, use sharepoint itself, and instead of using heroku to host it, use sharepoint.

Comment: Can Sharepoint even run Python code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that should be my first question. I've seen websites hosted on sharepoint, so I assumed that it's possible to run .js files, that is the only thing I know.